# GeoServer/JSP code="internalError"Rendering process

Tags: jsp, arcgis, geoserver

> code="internalError"Rendering process failed
>   The specified mark ttf://ESRI
>   Conservation#0x00A1 was not found!

I have this error. I just want to know where I can find the place where I can delete/add/update mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to add ESRI Conservation fonts (found on web) on my computer... if someone get the same problem.